# Add auto-Const in flutter in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have switched from vsCode to android studio for my flutter project as I think I feel comfortable reading the code In android studio

Though in vs code when i save the file the file gets formatted and it adds `const` keyword wherever my widget needed it

**PROBLEM**

In android studio neither the code gets formatted nor it adds const keyword wherever its needed

Please help with the 2 problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Flutter`
2. Under Editor Section check the `Format code on save` and `Organize imports on save` options and Apply changes.

Comment: Also is there not any way that android studio add const keyword where it is needed, as like vs code does... i will be grateful for that...
THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP & TIME

Comment: As my knowledge, there is no way to automatically add the const keywords in the android studio.

Comment: But you can use `dart fix --apply` command to fix all analyser issues underlined in the yellow color.

Comment: Yes thank you, though for now it adds const wherever it needs by executing the command you shared

Comment: Happy to help you! If you found this answer correct, you can mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by running the following command:

```
dart fix --apply
```

Answer (score 1):

As of my knowledge we have to manually add const keyword where we want...

Answer (score 0):

You can use macros for formatting and saving the document with just one shortcut

**Record the macro**

- Open any file in the editor.
- From the main menu, select Edit | Macros    | Start Macro Recording.
- Press ⌥⌘L to reformat code (Code | Reformat    Code ).
- Then press ⌘S to save all changes (File | Save All ). Android
  Studio/IntelliJ IDEA will show the performed actions in the status
  bar.
- Stop recording by selecting Edit | Macros | Stop Macro Recording.
- In the Enter Macro Name dialog, specify the name for the new macro
  and click OK.

**BIND THE MICRO WITH SHORTCUT**

- In the Settings/Preferences dialog ⌘,,
- select Keymap.Expand the Macros node and select the created Reformat
  and Save macro.
- Right-click the macro and choose Add Keyboard Shortcut in the context
  menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Ruo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You must follow these steps :-

1- Go to `File`  `Settings`   `Languages & Frameworks`   `Flutter`

[image]

2- check the Format code on save and Organize imports on save options and Apply changes.

[image]

4-  running the following command:`dart fix --apply`

[image]

5- res =>

```
after
```

[image]

```
before
```

[image]